# Parsing Array of dictionary to SQLite in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have JSON formatted data and I am trying to generate SQL insert statements so I could load the data in a table in an SQLite database.

My JSON looks like this :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "cities": [
                "Washington",
                "Washington"
            ],
            "num_buildings": 2,
            "building_ids": [
                "604159",
                "634589"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cities": [
                "Buffalo",
                "Buffalo",
                "Boston"
            ],
            "building_count": 3,
            "building_ids": [
                "652100",
                "676349",
                "652101"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I parse the JSON and I get a data structure as below.

```
{
cities =         (
    Washington,
    Washington
);
"num_buildings" = 2;
"event_ids" =         (
    604159,
    634589
  );
},
{
cities =         (
     Buffalo,
     Buffalo,
     Boston
);
"num_buildings" = 3;
"building_ids" =         (
     652100,
     676349,
     652101
  );
}
```

Next I want to generate SQL statements so I can load the data in a table.

```
NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [self JSONDictionaryForClassWithName:@"myJSON"];
NSArray *records = [JSONDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
  for (NSDictionary *record in records) {
  [self mergeRecordsForClassName:className forRecord:record] ;
};
NSLog(@"Initial sync recs are %@",records);
-(void)mergeRecordsForClassName:(NSString *)entityName forRecord:(NSDictionary *)record {
  NSString *insert_stmt2 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO %@("
    "city,building_count,building_id") values("
    "'%@',%i,'%@') ",
    entityName,
    [record valueForKey:@"cities"],
    [[record valueForKey:@"building_count"]  intValue],
    [record valueForKey:@"building_id"]
    ];
    NSLog(@"The insert stmt2 is %@",insert_stmt2);
}
```

It generates the SQL statement as below which obviously is wrong.

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO building(building_id,building_count,city) 
values('
  ("604159",
    "634589"
   )',
   3,
'(Washington,
  Washington'
)
)
```

How can I generate one SQL statement per row more like below:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO building(building_id,building_count,city) values('604159',3,;Washington');
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO building(building_id,building_count,city) values('634589',3,;Washington');
```

and so on

Thanks !

Comment: Per record, will there always be the same amount of cities and building_id values?  Your example seems to show that, but don't want to make that assumption.  Are these two properties basically parallel arrays?